# Csh how to compare the content of two files in different sequence?

Tags: compare, diff, csh

Need help in comparing the contents of two files (in different sequence and spacing) and output the difference in CSH. I tried diff -w file1 file2, somehow it doesn't work.

### file1

```
cat white 123
dog brown 234
duck black 567
rat grey  345
fish blue 456
```

### file2

```
fish               blue    456
rat                grey    345
dog                brown   234
```

### Output

```
cat white 123
duck black 567
```

### Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could `sort` these files first, then compare them with `diff`.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to work.
file1
-
    cat white 123
    dog brown 234
    duck black 567
    fish blue 456
    rat grey  345

file2
-
    dog                brown   234
    fish               blue    456
    rat                grey    345

output
-
    cat white 123 |   dog                brown   234
    dog brown 234 |   fish               blue    456
    duck black 567 |   rat                grey    345
    fish blue 456 <
    rat grey  345   <

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this problem by two steps:

1. squeeze spaces and sort lines

   ```
   perl -W -nE 's/\s+/ /g; say' file1.txt | sort > file1.sorted.txt
   perl -W -nE 's/\s+/ /g; say' file2.txt | sort > file2.sorted.txt
   ```
2. find out the common lines in them

   ```
   comm -3 file?.sorted.txt
   ```

Comment: Thanks... but i m running the script in csh.

Comment: @SpringW You could just put those commands in your csh script.